# Sync Framework : No changes getting uploaded

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I did some changes on the Sync tables to include extra columns added in recent times and just updated the sync table in the .Sync file. Now the problem is no changes are getting uploaded to server. I am using Sync over WCF with local db as .sdf file. Not sure if anybody faced similar issues, trying with search didnt yield any results of this issue. Any Sync framework expert advice on any areas to look into would be great.

Comment: enable sync fx tracing in verbose mode so you see what went wrong.